# Tableau report sharing

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop

We have a bunch of legacy tableau reports which we have published on the tableau server. We are planning to embed it onto a Drupal web page as well as internal Sharepoint site. The end users/agencies who need to view the report interactively are not part of our organization. I wanted to check if each of these end users will need any special license to view the reports and interact with it for example apply some filter in the report.

To give a gist of requirements we have our data warehouse built on Azure SQL. Using this data we need to develop a metric based report for each of the agencies that we work with. We need to then share it with them by embedding this report on a Drupal site where each agency has their separate login and they need to view metrics only specific to them.

We are non-profit and want to minimize the cost. If not Tableau is there any other effective way or any other BI tool which we can use.

Comment: Take a look to SeekTable as an alternative, it is good for embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Every person who uses Tableau needs a license (and MFA is coming this year to enforce that).

For end users outside your firewall, you will need the relevant firewall settings to allow the users to connect.

It might be more cost-effective to purchase Tableau Online (this is different to Tableau Server) licenses to allow them to get access to their workbooks.

Either way, you can embed dashboards in Drupal, WordPress, whatever but you must have a Tableau user license to login and use them (the other option is a Tableau Server Core license, but if you want to minimise cost this is probably not a viable option)